Which partitions from an old HDD need to be cloned to new SSD?
I just bought a new SSD for my old Asus N550JV laptop, planning to migrate the contents on old HDD using Macrium Reflect to new SSD.
I see that my laptop has following partitions:
Windows Disk Management:

Macrium Reflect:

I saw some online instructions using cmd reagentc /info to check which is the current recovery partition, the results are shown in this screenshot:

My questions are:

Should I clone partition 2 and 3?
I don't want to clone partition 6 (Data D:), can I still make the Partition 7 stays on the end of the SSD after I clone it using Macrium Reflect?
Is it safe to shrink the recovery partition?


You should clone the entire drive if you want the new SSD to be bootable into your OS

The recovery partition cannot be made smaller if you want a working recovery partition. You have been warned. All of those partitions are required

To put it bluntly, it's a mess. You have multiple recovery partitions likely the result of successive Windows installations. I wouldn't clone, at all. I would backup personal files and simply make a fresh installation in the new drive, end of story.

@ChanganAuto That was my first intention too, but after trying for quite a number of times using Media Creation Tool and also Rufus, I always get error of "Cannot install required file. Error 0x80070022 or 0x80070015 (not sure for this).

@Ramhound I am pretty sure this is the safest way to go

@nck927 - Unnecessary you can easily cleanup your unused WinRE partitions, the one near the EFI cannot be cleaned up, but the rest can. Trivial to recreate a working WinRE partition
